# Access the IP from a docker container on a bridge network on mac osx with docker-compose

Tags: macos, docker, hadoop, docker-compose

I am trying to access the webUIs from the containers on the docker-compose from a hadoop-cluster. Link: https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop

The Docker-Compose File had the following content:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.3-java8
    container_name: namenode
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.3-java8
    container_name: datanode
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.3-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.3-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.3-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

If I run the command "docker-compose up" I can see with docker ps the containers, and the opened ports. With network inspect I can see the IPs, but I cannot acces them.

I have found information about, that host networking on Mac OSX is not working. But this network is a bridge network.

How Can I acess the webUIs from the containers?

Comment: Only via the published `ports:`; on an OS X host you can never directly access the container-internal IP addresses.  Host networking won't help here.

Comment: I also cannot access the ports.. the container ip is: 172.x.x.5/16. with the port the adress is 172.x.x.5/16:9870. this works also not.

Comment: The container IP is useless; you shouldn't even try to look it up.  [Networking features in Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/) describes what works and what doesn't.

Comment: In the doc are examples for commands with docker run, but there are no informations about how can I do this with the docker-compose. are the commands same for both (docker run & docker-compose up) ?

Comment: `docker-compose exec datanode command`  will run `command` in the datanode container...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To access the Namenode UI, you'd use localhost:9870 since that's the port you've forwarded. You shouldn't need to access the UIs "from other containers"

And that's the only container you've opened a port forward for

Comment: I have add 127.0.0.1 before the ports in the compose file like: ports: - 127.0.0.1:9870:9870

Comment: You shouldn't need that. The port alone is fine